# Formatting Labels TKinter python 2.7

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/bry/Documents/Python/proj")
import stack

window = Tk()
colors=["gold","pink","blue","red","orange","purple","teal","green","yellow","violet","black","silver","white"]
firstGame = stack.blockWorldGame()

window.title("World Block Problem Simulator")
width_value = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0"%(width_value,height_value))

headerFrame = Frame(window)
headerFrame.pack()
headerLabel = Label(headerFrame , text="World Block Simulator!",fg="red",font="times 50 bold italic underline")
headerLabel.pack()
startingFrame = Frame(window)
startingFrame.pack()
startingProgramLabel = Label(startingFrame, text="Starting World Block State" , font="times 20 ")
startingProgramLabel.pack()
FrameContent = Frame(window)
FrameContent.pack()
for array in range([[A],[B,C],[D,E]]):
    frame = Frame(FrameContent)
    frame.pack(side=LEFT,expand=False)
    for block in range(len(firstGame.board[array])):#putting blocks in the same stack to the same frame
        blockLabel = Label(frame,text=firstGame.board[array][block],bg=colors[array],width=30,height=3)
        blockLabel.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Basically through this code i am attempting to reflect the board state as i solve the world block problem however i am having some issues in representing the blocks in the correct format on the GUI

Upon running this set of code i will get the result of A,BC,DE. However A block wont be reflected at the same position of B where it should be, it will be floating at a height in the middle of both B & C.

Can someone tell me how to make it such that A is inline with B and D
[image]

Comment: The code you put up does not help in replicating the problem. Do read up on providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pack the `blockLabel` from bottom to top inside `frame` as below:

```
for array in range([[A],[B,C],[D,E]]):
    frame = Frame(FrameContent)
    frame.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y) # added fill=Y
    for block in range(len(firstGame.board[array])):
        blockLabel = Label(frame,text=firstGame.board[array][block],bg=colors[array],width=30,height=3)
        blockLabel.pack(side=BOTTOM) # added side=BOTTOM
```